# Retrigerable Monostable Multivibrator that fires on both rising and falling edge.

Tags: low-power, cmos, schmitt-trigger, multivibrator

I have a need to generate an active low pulse when a switch is depressed AND when it is released and keep the component count and PCB real estate as low as possible (while still allowing me to manually rework).  Schmitt Triggering would be nice too - after all it is a switch.  Oh and it is a portable 3.3vdc device so power is a supreme concern.

I have a solution using two MOSFETs and a hand full of resistors and caps - not true Schmitt Triggering but pretty good debounce.  But I was wondering if something like the SN74LVC1G123DCUR could be employed to get my component count down.

SN74LVC1G123DCUR is half a low voltage CMOS version of the 74123 with only a single one-shot and a tidy little 8 pin package.  But from the data sheet it does not appear to me that you can simply tie the -A and +B inputs together and accomplish my goal.  Can anyone tell me if this is doable or if it can be accomplished with another small footprint IC?

Comment: (ignoring debouncing the switch for a moment) looks like a job for a small delay and an XOR gate. This gives a pulse the length of the delay, for every edge of a square wave. Delay can be an R-C, an L-C, or a short cable or PCB trace (about 6-8 inches per nanosecond)

Comment: Do not discount a small processor.  Some are very inexpensive and in the end will generally save you time and parts as they are very flexible.

Comment: Not using any debouncing, on the other hand, is likely to result in it triggering on both press and release anyway.  Though maybe more than you want.  @BrianDrummond's method is more sensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single section of CD14538 should do it. It has Schmitt-trigger inputs, whereas CD4098 doesn't. Detecting both edges can be done by feeding the signal to both trigger inputs, with a slight skew between them. The minimum specified trigger pulse width for CD14538 is 140ns, so adding a 500ns RC time constant to either trigger input should work and be conservative. Internally, the skewed trigger edges will form a trigger pulse.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7TDhG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The time constant is about 0.5us. The output is not delayed compared to input. The time between the input transitions, independently of polarity, should be probably 1-2us minimum.

The diodes, in order of preference, would be:

- RF Schottky, e.g. 1N5711
- Ultrafast high conductance, e.g. 1N4454
- Signal, e.g. 1N4148
- General purpose rectifier, e.g. 1N4001

I think the circuit will work with any diode, especially from 5V and above, but the RF Schottky types will leave the best margins all the way down to 3V.

If the input has very slow edges, the time constant should be increased, or a separate Schmitt-trigger buffer should be added between the external input and the trigger circuit.

A more integrated approach uses XOR gates to provide the level-insensitive trigger pulse:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvTR7E.png)</sup>

The circuits above should work down to 3.0V.

Comment: Both good solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Combining a debounce (2 cross coupled nand gates) and two negative edge detectors gets something like this.

[image]

The circuit uses a small footprint, low voltage version of the 4011 quad 2 input NAND (74LVX00 or similar) and suitable values for R and C (to create the monostable pulse widths). A third nand gate combines the two pulses into a single pulse train and the final nand gate inverts the signal giving two complimentary outputs

Comment: This is lovely.  Second stage is similar to our current FET based solution.

Answer (score 0):

In line with st2000's comment, I would at least consider using a very small microcontroller.

An [attiny4](http://www.atmel.com/devices/ATTINY4.aspx) costs 31 cents in quantity, runs from 1.8 to 5V, and provides 4 GPIOs with ~0.5V of input hysteresis. The code to implement what you want would also be pretty simple.

Comment: Ironically, my application is to wake a sleeping microcontroller so it may process the button press and release and then go right back to sleep to conserve battery life.  The attiny4 may save me pennies but I am going to lose big on milliamps...

Comment: I looked over the attiny4.  Adorable.  And the power consumption is not as bad as I feared.  But I can still do better with discrete components (the FET solution eats a mere 66na).  Mostly, it doesn't feel like adding another uP to this project is going to simplify my life.  But thank you for your input.

Comment: @Frobozz Make sure your FET solution stays below 100nA all the way over the operating temperature range. If the device you're making is likely to be transported in a car, assume that the guts may be 60-80C.